# C# и DropBox - проверить скопирован ли файл?

Tags: c#, файлы, dropbox

Вопрос достаточно простой, но не простой. Есть папка на DropBox, куда время от времени попадает небольшой текстовый файл. Есть программа, которая с помощью FileSysmemWatcher отлавливает событие OnCreate, выжидает некоторое время, потом стримридером, проверяет - не заблокирован ли файл и копирует его в другую папку не связанную с DropBox. Опять некоторое время выжидает, сравнивает файлы и если все Ок, удаляет оригинал и работает уже с копией.

Вопрос в том, можно ли как то адекватно проверить что файл все таки полноценно скопировался (синхронизирован)? Есть конечно вариант подключать библиотеку DropBox, разбираться в ней и т.д. (Мне этот вариант кажется излишним, хоть и даст 100% гарантию) Но возможно кто то сталкивался с подобной задачей - держит ли DropBox  файл в блокировке, на время его синхронизации, например. Как проверить? Не пишет ли DropBox файлы частями? Повторюсь - размер файла не более 200-300 Кб и на синхронизацию, уходят секунды.

Comment: как правило если у вас не возникло никаких exception-ов то это значит, что все прошло хорошо.

Comment: @IgorIlyichyov Не возникает, потому что все еще в процессе. Я просто думаю как лучше сделать

Answer (score 2):

Ну 100% гарантию Вам даже Билл Гейтс не даст, но:
DropBox по идее не должен держать файл в блокировке
Более простой способ и наверняка самый верный это сравнение по ХЕШ,
сравните хеш-и файлов.